# borderTopStartRadius VS borderTopLeftRadius and borderTopEndRadius VS borderTopRightRadius differences

Tags: react-native

I am very curious, both of them are similar in React Native, are there any differences between them?

`borderTopLeftRadius` vs `borderTopStartRadius`

And

`borderTopRightRadius` vs `borderTopEndRadius`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The borderRadius prop is used to give a curve from all the corners. But to give a specific curve to a particular corner we use other specific props like,

`borderTopLeftRadius 
borderTopRightRadius
borderTopStartRadius
borderTopEndRadius`

But behaviour of some props are the same as,

`borderTopLeftRadius` and `borderTopStartRadius`

`borderTopRightRadius` and `borderTopEndRadius`

So, answer to your question is both the props are the same.

Comment: alright, I wanted to double confirm since it doesn't show any difference at all. thank you for the information.

Comment: Start is better because it does not assume that the order is left to right

Comment: I thought using row-reverse would make the start and end version flip but it doesn't. If anyone wants a visual example, I've created it here: https://snack.expo.dev/@paulwongx/borderradius